# use the array .forEach function to iterate over users and populate the SELECT UI element with OPTION elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, foreach, populate

1. Create a displayUsers arrow function. It should take a users parameter
2. It should use the array .forEach function to iterate over users and populate the SELECT UI element with OPTION elements. Each OPTION should have its value set to the id of a given user, while its display text should be set to the user's name
3. We can see a sample user in our app; a certain Charles Odili from Nigeria! Add a new user object (e.g representing yourself) to the users array in fetchAndDisplayUsers. Feel free to not use real data values, but ensure the id is different from that of the existing user.

The above instruction was given to follow in order to achieve my result but my code below in displayUsers function seem to not be working...
I keep getting this error message "Create a "displayUsers" function that iterates over its parameter and updates the UI. See the instructions for details."

```
  const users = [];

  const displayUsers = (users) => {
    users.forEach((user) => {
      const option = document.createElement("OPTION");
      const name = document.createTextNode(user.name);
      option.value = user.id;
      option.appendChild(name);
      document.querySelector('select').appendChild(option);
    });
  }

  const fetchAndDisplayUsers = () => {
    users.push({
      age: 40,
      weight: 75,
      height: 6,
      country: 'Nigeria',
      name: 'Charles Odili',
      id: 'dfhb454768DghtF'
    });

    displayUsers(users);
  };
```

Note: The problem here is not with fetchAndDisplayUsers function but with displayUsers function.

Comment: opt.value=users.id should be opt.value=user.id

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const users = [];

  const displayUsers = (users) => {
    let sel = document.querySelector('.select-text');
    users.forEach((user) => {
      let opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value=users.id;
      opt.innerHTML += user.name
      sel.appendChild(opt);
    });
  }

  const fetchAndDisplayUsers = () => {
    users.push({
      age: 40,
      weight: 75,
      height: 6,
      country: 'Nigeria',
      name: 'Charles Odili',
      id: 'dfhb454768DghtF'
    });

    displayUsers(users);
  }; 

window.onload = function(){
  fetchAndDisplayUsers();  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select class="select-text"></select>
</body>
</html>
```